# Distributions Supported at a Point of a Variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, differential-operators

Let $X$ be a smooth algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$, let $a\in X$ be a closed point, and $R=\mathcal{O}_{X,a}$ the local ring at $a$.  Write $\mathfrak{m}$ for the maximal ideal of $R$.

Define the distributions of order $\leq n$ supported at $a$, written $Dist^n(X,a)$ to be the vector space of linear maps $\varphi:R\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $\varphi(\mathfrak{m}^{n+1})=0$.  Then define $Dist(X,a)=\bigcup\limits_{n\geq 0}Dist^n(X,a)$.

Let $V\subseteq Vec(X)$ be a linear subspace of vector fields on $X$ such that the evaluation  map $V\to T_a(X)$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces.

Choose a basis $X_1,\dots,X_n$ of $V$.  Let $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ denote the commutative polynomial algebra in the indeterminates $x_1,\dots,x_n$.  Then we have a linear map $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]\to Dist(X,a)$ by sending $p(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ to the distribution which sends a function $f\in R$ to $$(p(X_1,\dots,X_n)(f))(a),$$ and here we write the monomials in $p$ according to the ordering on the variables (e.g. the polynomial $x_2^2x_3x_1$ will evaluate on $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ to $X_1X_2^2X_3$).

My question is: is this map an isomorphism of vector spaces?  If not, under what conditions on $V$, say, is it an isomorphism?

Either a reference or an explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: But I'm taking commutative polynomials, so your example doesn't apply.
In the case of $V=\mathfrak{g}$, the statement is true by the PBW theorem.
I edited the statement to make the commutativity condition more explicit.

Comment: Oh yes, of course, you're right. Deleted my comment.